# Will_filter gem generate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I get the error below when trying to install the will_filter gem, running the following command: rails generate will_filter

```
C:\Sites\eyesproject>rails generate will_filter
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action
_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:191:in `normalize_conditions!': You should not use t
he `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (RuntimeErro
r)
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]`
 option.
If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:
  Instead of: match "controller#action"
  Do: get "controller#action"
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:67:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1438:in `new'
```

my routes.rb:

```
Eyesproject::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :project_details

  resources :welcomes

get "sessions/new"
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
  root 'welcome#index'
  get "welcome/index"

end
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: I guess it is `will_filter` bug coupling with transition on rails 4. Maybe you can find it in open issue. In Rails 4 you strongly should use `via` with `match`.

Comment: Last commit 6 months ago. I suggest you to find another solution, or maybe there is a live fork of this repo.

Comment: Did you add `mount WillFilter::Engine => "/will_filter"`?

Comment: yes, that has been added, I get the same error